# Is Base64 NSData universal?

Tags: ios, base64, nsdata

Does encoding `NSData` as base64 work cross-platform? If I base64 encode an image on iOS and upload it somewhere (let's say AWS S3), will I then be able to download and display that image on other platforms?

Comment: This depends a great deal on the location of that mysterious "somewhere". If it happens to be a place that supports standard base64 decoding, the answer is "yes". Otherwise, the answer is "no".

Comment: Ok let's just say AWS S3 then.

Comment: There is an [RFC 3458](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3548) for that. So it should work everywhere.

Comment: @startupthekid But AWS S3 is only a storage place, of course you'd be able to get your data back in the same base64 format. It's a matter of decoding it after you read it.

Comment: Right, my question is if I encode it on iOS can I then successfully decode it on other platforms.